# Is there dh_make on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, packaging, deb

Is there any way to run dh_make on Mac OS?
There's no such package as 'dh-make' in macports or brew. 
May be there're tools which perform similar operation? Or the only way is to set up package manually? :(

Answer (score 0):

No, dh_make on macs. This is only available for debian based OS.While mac is based on BSD codebase